# Parse and Display Table from HTML String in NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: html, ios, swift, uitableview

I have been in the process of converting my Android/Java app into iOS/Swift, and have run into an issue regarding table generation.

The app displays a list of content pulled from a web source as html strings, and displays these in a UITableView (RecyclerView on Android). Creating an NSMutableAttributedString with NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType works fine for basic html formatting (bold, italics, lists, etc), but I need to render tables as well.

In my Android app, I created blocks of content split at  tags, and if it was a table, populated a TableView and inserted it into the correct place in the text using a LinearLayout.

The cells are programmatically generated in Swift, so I pre-process the HTML when pulled from the web and store the NSMutableAttributedStrings in an array along with the estimated heights in order to make scrolling smooth. I ran across the [NSTextTable in Apple's](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstexttable) documentation, but cannot seem to figure out how to use this class, and whether they can be embedded in an NSMutableAttributedString in order to access the table later.

If I'm totally misunderstanding what that class does, please let me know.